# Workflow send an Email Action intermittently sends email to correct email

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, send-email

I'm looking for help with trying to troubleshoot an issue I'm having with a workflow I created in designer 2010.

The workflow has a total of 14 steps, I'm not sure if there is a limit. It is currently set to start when a new item is created. Within each step I have an action to send an Email and to stop the workflow.

For each step I've used a different email address in the To field, however, when I've created multiple new items sometimes the intended person receives the email and sometimes they don't. I have confirmed the email that isn't being received is actually going to someone else's email in a different step. Can someone explain why this might be occurring and/or how I can fix this?

I am pretty inexperienced with designer and this is the first time I've created a SharePoint workflow. Feedback is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Trying using the LOG command - you can make Sharepoint log something to the Workflow History - e.g. Step 1 ok, Step 2 ok and so on.  If you don't see a 'Step 3 ok', then there could be something wrong in Step 3.  One other comment - I'm wondering about the 'stop workflow' that you're using, is it perhaps stopping the workflow too soon?  Finally, perhaps it's worth checking for workflows (including old version workflows) that might still be running; perhaps these need stopping in order for the new version of the workflow to run correctly.